# how to make this code print 1 2 3 4 5 6

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have this code changed, but is not working to print 1 2 3 4 5 6
what is missing??
I have tried to put two mutexes one between each creation of the thread, and another one when they are printed, but i always get 3 4 5 6 1 2.
Thanks in advance.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutex_t mutexd;
void *th(void *arg){
int *tmp=(int*)arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexd);
    printf("%d\t",tmp[0]);
    printf("%d\t",tmp[1]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexd);

}

int main(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexd,NULL);

    pthread_t threads[3];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&attr,PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
    int t[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&threads[0],&attr,th,(void *)t);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&threads[1],&attr,th,(void *)(t+2));
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    pthread_create(&threads[2],&attr,th,(void *)(t+4));
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<THREADS;i++){
            pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: have you tried to step throw a debugger?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't matter in which order you create the threads, the operating system can still run your main thread a little longer and doesn't have to switch to a thread immediately it's created.

Comment: it should be with multithreading, debugging is not an option. thanks

Comment: As for how to solve the problem, you might want to look into [condition variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables).

Comment: @user2371816 'debugging is not an option' - in that case, you cannot develop software and you should stop trying.

Comment: debugging is not an option because if you want the threads to be deterministic they will be because you are running the code line by line, so the parallelism is not reached. The goal is to achieve the parallelism and make the program always print 1 2 3 4 5 6 independently if it is debugged or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thread don't usually work in the same order that they written in your code . in order to achieve this move each join to be after the creation of the thread.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutex_t mutexd;
void *th(void *arg)
{
    int *tmp=(int*)arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexd);
    printf("%d\t",tmp[0]);
    printf("%d\t",tmp[1]);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexd);

}

int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexd,NULL);

    pthread_t threads[3];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&attr,PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);


    int t[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    pthread_create(&threads[0],&attr,th,(void *)t);
     pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&threads[1],&attr,th,(void *)(t+2));
     pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&threads[2],&attr,th,(void *)(t+4));
     pthread_join(threads[2],NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;


}
```

this code should work fine